# Save User Meta Email Address in Lowercase

Tags: hooks, actions, user-meta

I'm looking for a way to save all email addresses to user meta as lowercase, ideally without validating and asking the user to change it but instead just saving it as lowercase. I've got as far as the following but can't get it to work:

```
add_action( 'update_user_meta', 'meta_email_tolowercase', 10, 4 );
function meta_email_tolowercase( $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value ) {

    if( strpos( $_meta_value, '@' ) !== false && ! ctype_lower( $_meta_value ) ):

        $result = update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $meta_key, strtolower( $_meta_value ) );

    endif;
}
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no such action hook `update_user_meta`. Where/how is this being applied? If you're doing this on a profile update or something, just apply `strtolower()` directly to the specific meta field you are targeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this filter to do that

```
add_filter("sanitize_email", function ($sanitized_email, $email, $message) {

    $sanitized_email = strtolower($sanitized_email);

    return $sanitized_email;

}, 10, 3);
```

but I am not sure if using "strtolower" is a good idea, does another readers know if it's better to use "mb_strtolower" to handle multibyte characters ?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: Awesome, thanks, @Kaperto. That's worked like a charm.